# Number of moles of Grignard reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry

How many moles of Grignard reagent required by one mole of the below compound?
That is,

[image]

I think it should be 4, two for each carbonyl.

But in mybook it is given as 7 .

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @Zhe but in my book it is given as 7

Comment: Oh, well, looks like we both missed the naphthol moiety on the left, plus the thiol... I think that puts us at 6. Still look for 7...

Comment: @Zhe what is naphthol moiety

Comment: The OH on the left is acidic. The thiol as well. These will react to destroy 2 equivalents of Grignard reagent.

Comment: @Zhe how OH can react . What would be the product when OH is reacted

Comment: $\ce{RO-}$? It's exactly like what would happen if you put your Grignard reagent in water.

Comment: @Zhe If I remember correctly, I think tBuLi would react with the alkyl chloride (eliminating HCl). I don't know if Grignards are the same.

Comment: @orthocresol Had the exact same thought. Unfortunately, I don't think this is a great pathway since that would mean that Grignard generation destroys a lot of the alkyl halide used to make it...

Comment: @Zhe true, true...

Comment: I don't know about the alkyl chloride either.  It's true that Grignard reagents, like lithium reagents, can disproportionate and exchange, but I expect everything else to happen more rapidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given compound 
1) grignard reagent will act as a nucleophile and attack twice on both carbonyl groups. So 4 moles here 
2) it will act as a base and react with the phenol, thiol, and chloride group. So 3 moles here 
Therefore a total of 7 moles will be required

Comment: Can you please give me an example of acting as a base

Comment: This might help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grignard_reaction